# react native: check Android background activities setting

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I want my application to check whether its background activity is enabled in the Android settings.

```
Settings => Apps & notifications => Advanced => Apps background activities
```

I'm aware about the `react-native-device-info` package but I didn't see any method relating to the background activities.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

'`react-native-device-info`' does not know your app status. This module is the module that you use when you need it for information on that device. For example, `UUID` value, `APPID` value, etc.

`AppState` can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background, and notify you when the state changes.

- `active` - The app is running in the foreground
- `background` - The app is running in the background. The user is
  either:

  - in another app
  - on the home screen
  - [Android] on another    Activity (even if it was launched by your
    app)

### Example

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native';

class AppStateExample extends Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  };

  render() {
    return <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>;
  }
}
```

[FCM Document](http://%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Background Restricted Apps (Android P or higher)

Beginning January 2019, FCM will not forward messages to apps with background restrictions (e.g., Settings-> Apps and Notifications-> [appname] batteries). When an app is removed from the background limit, a new message about the app is delivered as before.

Have a look at  [the part about "remote push notifications"](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/trouble-shooting.md):

Comment: Actually I want my app to be able to get notifications even when it is closed/killed.
But, if my app background activity setting is disabled (which it is by default) the user will never be aware of notifications.
That is why I want my app to detect its background activity status at starting to inform the user (in case it's disabled).

Comment: If the notification you are talking about is push message, you can receive push message even in the background.

Comment: I know that, but the background state is no longer available once your app is closed or killed. I spent many hours to figure out why I couldn't get the pushed messages when the app is closed.  The answer is that my app background activity was disabled in the smartphone settings, hence my question.

Comment: FCM Document https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: "remote push notifications": https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/trouble-shooting.md